# Zabbix timing out when sending Slack notification, but alerts are still send

Tags: slack, zabbix

I have a question regarding the Slack Webhooks for Zabbix. I've configured Zabbix to send Slack messages when a trigger of any kind is triggered. However the alerts are send, but zabbix does not recognize that the messages have been send, as seen in the pictures below:
[Slack Alerts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HR2wT.png)
[Slack Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zodhS.png)

The Error messages state: `Slack notification failed : Error: cannot get URL: Timeout was reached`

Resolved Message: `Slack notification failed : channel_not_found`

I've followed [this](https://www.zabbix.com/integrations/slack) tutorial for the Slack intergration.

My configuration is as follows:
[Actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vekre.png),
[Zabbix Admin user Media](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeYLb.png)

on Zabbix 4.4.7

Hopefully someone can help me with this!

Answer (score 0):

if you use HTTPProxy parameter, modify script as follows:

```
function getPermalink(channelId, messageTimestamp, httpProxy) {
    var req = new CurlHttpRequest();

    if (typeof httpProxy === 'string' && httpProxy.trim() !== '') {
        req.SetProxy(httpProxy);
    }
```

and

```
        result.tags.__message_link = getPermalink(resp.channel, resp.ts, params.HTTPProxy);
```